# Android hide own app icon not working in some of android 10 devices

Tags: android, android-10.0

```
AppPackageManager loAppPackageManager = new AppPackageManager(foContext);
  if (isAppHidden()) {
      loAppPackageManager.disableComponent(".Splash");
  } else {
      loAppPackageManager.enableComponent(".Splash");
  }
```

AppPackageManager.java

```
// Disable Application component
public void disableComponent(String fsClassName) {
    fsClassName = msPackageName + fsClassName;
    moPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(
            msPackageName, fsClassName),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Log.i(TAG, "Disabled: " + fsClassName);
    Common.removeShortcut(moContext);
}

// Enable Application component
public void enableComponent(String fsClassName) {
    fsClassName = msPackageName + fsClassName;
    moPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(
            msPackageName, fsClassName),
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Log.i(TAG, "Enabled: " + fsClassName);
}
```

Common.java

```
public static void removeShortcut(Context foContext) {
    // Deleting shortcut for MainActivity
    // on Home screen
    Intent loShortcutIntent = new Intent(foContext, Splash.class);
    loShortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    Intent loAddIntent = new Intent();
    loAddIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, loShortcutIntent);
    loAddIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, foContext.getString(R.string.APP_NAME));
    loAddIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    loAddIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    foContext.sendBroadcast(loAddIntent);
}
```

I read somewhere these method did not work from `Android 10(R)`, but for me it is not working on some of the `Android 10(Q)` devices.

Like I checked in Nokia 6.1 Plus(10), Samsung s9(10), Emulator(10) in these devices it did not work, if I execute above code the app icon still visible and on click it redirect to settings > app info screen, while i click on foreground service notification it redirect me to particular activity.

In RealMe X2 and C3 (10) I checked, the app icon hide properly.

I need exact reason and solution for this, app depends on this functionality only, if there is any alternate way, please let me know.

Comment: I had seen one app whose icon got hidden after I enabled hide icon in Android 10. So there is a way. Don't know how.

Comment: Did you found any solution so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide app icon in Android 10 or later.